# How to insert multiple records in a certain Tag of the same node?

Tags: nebula-graph, graph-query

Assume that there is a `tag` named "houses", which represents which houses people have. When `insert houses`, the house information will overwrite by the new one. How to achieve this requirement of a person owning multiple houses?

Tag information:

```
CREATE TAG houses (
code string NOT NULL COMMENT "ID",
name string NOT NULL COMMENT "Name",
... ...
) COMMENT = "house information";
```

If one ID has several houses, how to write the `query statement` to avoid the situation of previous inserting being replaced?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `tag` for the `property` , rather than using the same tag as the person.

Then the `person` and the `house` are associated through a `relationship`.